# Jasmine tests check if html contains text and return boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
expect(view.$el.html()).toContain('Admin');
```

The view does contain the word 'Admin' so I was expecting it to return true. How can I achieve this?

```
expect(view.$el.html()).toContain('Admin');
```

This returns `undefined`. How can I make it return `true`?

```html
<header class="main">
  <div id="heading">
    <ul class="header-view right">
      <li class="inline"><a href="#link" class="button help-btn tab-btn"><span>  </span>Help</a></li>
      <li class="inline last"><a href="#og" class="button admin-btn tab-btn expand-admin"><span></span>Admin</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

This is what is returned from `view.$el.html`

Please help.

Comment: please share some relevant html code and mention all jquery libraries that you are using. Also try to reproduce your problem on jsfiddle link and share it.

Comment: `view.$el.html()` what it returns

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar i am new to jasmine- i dont know if i can use jsfiddle for it! i only use jquery-backbone. No other libraries

Comment: Hi Spdexter, would you mind to update the correct answer as the one provided by @alecxe please? The actual one marked as correct is outdated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the Jasmine docs:

> The 'toContain' matcher is for finding an item in an **Array**

You are trying to find a string inside a string so I would do something like this:

```
expect(view.$el.html().indexOf('Admin') !== -1).toBe(true);
```

Comment: `toMatch` can also be used:
`expect(view.$el.html()).toMatch('Admin')`.

The `toMatch` matcher is for regular expressions.

Comment: Please update the answer as this is both a bad way of solving it and outdated.

Answer (score 92):

`toContain()` now [can actually be used for substring in string checks](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/981):

```
expect(view.$el.html()).toContain('Admin');
```

Comment: Somehow this is not working for me error ===> ✗ change version: BData details page
        - Expected 'https://xxx/data-objects/NS_PROTRACTOR_TEST_DL42/DATA_LINEAGE_TEST/PRC/ORC/0/versionTest/0' to match '/data-objects/NS_PROTRACTOR_TEST_DL42/DATA_LINEAGE_TEST/PRC/ORC/0/versionTest/0;'.

I am using contain to check substring

Comment: Actually, it does work - I was just doing the check against the nativeElement instead of the actual text. My bad!

Comment: `const content: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
expect(content.innerHTML).toContain('Admin');` for those looking for equivalent on angular 2.